# hex stream to UTF string with C#

Tags: c#, wireshark, packet

i captured tcp packets by using `wireshark`.

but `wireshark` can not decode bytes to UTF unicode.

so i copied packet's hex stream to notepad.

i have hex stream, like this

`2016d818bf420810771517200800450000344a9e40003306a1367a26201ec0a801030a6027562d9b0555e97454b78010fe8889aa00000101080a0016a11302854c19`

i want decode hex stream to readable UTF string. with C# .NET.

can you help me?

thank you for reading.

Comment: check here: http://www.nullskull.com/faq/834/convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string-in-net.aspx

Comment: You need to know the encoding for the source data. Is it ASCII/ANSI?

Comment: sorry for late response. the link is very helpful.

Comment: Matthew Watson//i don't know.. but i think its not ascii nor ansi. if it is, i could read the string with `wireshark`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the  int.Parse(string, NumberStyles.HexNumber)

or try to converto to byte

System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)

Comment: Both of them will not work for the sample hex string in question.

Comment: i tried this, it didn't worked. but it's helpful for me. thankyou!